# Use the same project for EMF model and edit code?

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf

Can I somehow use **the same Eclipse plug-in project** for both a generated **EMF model** and the corresponding generated **EMF Edit** code?

Normally these two components reside in two different projects, the EMF Edit one with the suffix `.edit` to its name. I find this superfluous, since there is so little code in the Edit project, and it is so closely related to the model code.

I have tried setting both the `modelDirectory` and the `editDirectory` Gen Model attributes to (different) directories in the same project, but that seems to lead to endless confusion and build problems. I think maybe the two generation steps overwrite each others project setting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experimentation it seems like it works fine to have EMF and EMF Edit generated code in the same project.

The things I had to do to make it work are the following:

1. Setting the genmodel property `modelDirectory` and `editDirectory` to **the same** directory. Otherwise I got a build error saying *"The type ... is already defined in ..."*.
2. Setting the genmodel property `bundleManifest="false"`. Otherwise the plug-in ID is overwritten by the generation process.

Apart from this I also set `updateClasspath="false"` to avoid that the generation process messes around with that.

---

The automatic updates to the manifest and `plugin.xml` files seem to be the following:

1. Set plug-in ID
2. Add exported packages
3. Add EMF extensions to `plugin.xml`

2 and 3 needs to be performed manually if they are desired. That would involve adding entries to `plugin.xml` similar to these:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.generated_package">
   <!-- @generated model -->
   <package
         uri="somePackage"
         class="somePackage.SomePackage"
         genModel="model/model.xcore"/>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.emf.edit.itemProviderAdapterFactories">
   <!-- @generated model -->
   <factory
         uri="somePackage"
         class="somePackage.someClass"
         supportedTypes=
           "org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider.IEditingDomainItemProvider
            org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider.IStructuredItemContentProvider
            org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider.ITreeItemContentProvider
            org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider.IItemLabelProvider
            org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider.IItemPropertySource"/>
</extension>
```